# ITMS-90433: Invalid Swift Support - EAS Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to publish the app to the apple store with expo and EAS. Once I try and submit my app through apple store connect I got an email that says the following.

ITMS-90433: Invalid Swift Support - The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just modify the code signature of libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

I didn't use Xcode so I assume I have a problem with expo/eas or the code itself. Does anyone know anything I can do?

Comment: Hi, I also experienced the same issue. I saw you left a forum post also and the comment on there was that the provisioning profile was of the wrong type i.e. not production. I think its unlikely that I did this although possible so I updated my eas cli to the latest 0.60.0 and did another build. It has since gone through and been accepted. If someone else is experiencing this, frustratingly it just seems to be update eas and try again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also experiencing this issue. I upgraded EAS to the latest 1.1.1 and also re-installed xcode on my machine just in case. Re-built and am getting the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I've had (with `eas --version`)

`eas-cli/0.52.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.0`

with

```
npm install -g eas-cli
# or
yarn global add eas-cli
```

I got it updated to

`eas-cli/2.1.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.0`

and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating xCode to 14.0.
Updating the eas-cli version did not solve it for me, the problem still remained.
I got it working ok again after the following steps:

1. Clear bundler cache: https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-macos-linux/
2. Added the --clear-cache flag to my eas build command
3. Rebooted my computer

After this I created a new build with eas and it no longer had the error.